# Validate iframe request to domain-2 after login to the main page of domain-1

Tags: session, authentication, iframe, cross-domain, token

I have a parent web application with authentication (user/password).

I want to open an embedded (child) iframe in my application to **another domain** of mine, that will approve the request due to fact I already authenticated in the parent. The other domain doesn't aware of my user / password, so I really need some kind of approval that this is a valid request.

I'm aware of the cross-domain restrictions, and I was wondering what's the best practice here. I have no problem creating tokens or what ever need on my main domain server, but I don't know what's the right work flow here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate a token when the parent page is rendered and then pass it  when requesting the iframe content from your other domain:

```
<iframe src="https://another-domain.com?token=XXYY" width="10" height="10"></iframe>
```

However, this implies that you have a way to validate this token on your other server.